# Load test for Registration page in jmeter

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

I have a thread group with register page.
Iam try to do concurrent unique users registrations as much as my website can handle.
Till now I have recoded script for single user for registering and parameterizing with different unique users data manually in csv file and replacing in recorded script. But it is difficult to modify for huge no of users while registering.
Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing registration process you don't need a pre-defined data set as you are creating users "on-the-fly". Therefore you can use random data instead of pre-defined, for example

- if you need an email you can generate one using [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function like:

  ```
  ${__RandomString(15,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)}@example.com
  ```
- if you need a random date (for example of birth) you can use [__RandomDate()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate) function like:

  ```
  ${__RandomDate(,1950-01-01,2018-01-01,,)}
  ```
- if you need a random number - go for [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function

  ```
  ${__Random(0,9999999,)}
  ```
- if you need a totally unique identifier - use [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function

  ```
  ${__UUID}
  ```
- you can get current timestamp in different formats with [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function

  ```
  ${__time(EEEE\, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a,)}
  ```

Demo of above functions:

[image: JMeter Functions Unique Data]

More information on JMeter Functions: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: I simply know how much of users can handle my application.Is there any chance to repeat the same data if I use random function , for easier convenient me?